# Convert NULLs to NAs in a list

Tags: r, list, purrr

Would you suggest a better (briefer or more legible) way of converting NULLs in a list to NAs; and from list to vector?

```r
list(1, 2, 3, numeric(0), 5) %>%
  purrr::map_dbl(~ ifelse(length(.) == 0, NA_real_, .))
# [1]  1  2  3 NA  5
```

I would prefer not using `ifelse` and instead using `if_else`.
Is there another way of doing it with purrr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the length of each element of a list is 0 or 1 (e.g. `lst.1`), you could simply use

```r
lst.1 %>% map_dbl(1, .default = NA)

# [1]  1  2  3 NA  5
```

A general way to deal with a list with different length in each element (e.g. `lst.2`) is

```r
lst.2 %>%
  map_if(~ length(.) == 0, ~ NA) %>%
  flatten_dbl()

# [1]  1  2  3 NA  5
```

---

###### Data

```
lst.1 <- list(1, 2, 3, numeric(0), 5)
lst.2 <- list(1:3, numeric(0), 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

If L is the list then any of these work:

```
replace(L, lengths(L) == 0, NA)

ifelse(lengths(L), L, NA)
```

No packages needed.